# Using vinkla/hashids package in Laravel 5.2 to obsfucate id's in URL's

Tags: php, laravel-5, hashids

I have installed and configured the latest version (2.3.0) of vinkla/hashids on laravel 5.2.

I'm unsure how to implement its functionality on my URL routes.

I want to obsfucate all id attributes which are displayed in my URL routes.

For example- http://localhost:8000/profile/3/edit should become http://localhost:8000/profile/xyz/edit.

I have tried overriding the following method on  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php by adding it to App\Profile.php as so-

```
public function getRouteKey()
{
dd('getRouteKey method');
    return Hashids::encode($id);
}
```

My dd is not displaying so I'm not overriding it correctly.

Please can you advise how I should implement this functionality correctly?

Thanks

Comment: For future readers. I found that really helpfull: https://gist.github.com/TheNodi/3a69c00e485ebcfee569a7476193d36e

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I have been doing for the same problem:

Say your routes has

```
Route::get('/profile/{profile}', 'ProfileController@showProfile');
```

Then in model:

```
// Attribute used for generating routes
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'hashid';
}

// Since "hashid" attribute doesn't "really" exist in
// database, we generate it dynamically when requested
public function getHashidAttribute()
{
    return Hashids::encode($this->id);
}

// For easy search by hashid
public function scopeHashid($query, $hashid)
{
    return $query->where('id', Hashids::decode($hashid)[0]);
}
```

Finally you need to bind the route parameter "profile". You have to decode it first, then search in database (default binding won't work). So, in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    Route::bind('profile', function($hashid, $route) {
        try {
            return Profile::hashid($hashid)->first();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            abort(404);
        }
    });

    parent::boot($router);
}
```

Comment: I did not want to use explicit binding, I would like to know how to do this in some implicit binding...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki That would require having the hashed field in the database as well. Do you want that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe changing "getRouteKeyName" value is not necessary though.